# Write many columns (more than 20)

Tags: python

I want to know an efficient and simple way to write many columns to a single file with Python.

For example, I have `a` and `b` arrays with a size of 20 for N rows.
each row has a different `a` and `b`.

I would like to write a file with a format like this:

Names of each column

```
0 a[0] b[0] a[1] b[1] ... a[19] b[19]

1 a[0] b[0] a[1] b[1] ....a[19] b[19]
```

I can only think this way:

```
data = open(output_filename,'w') 
for i in range(0, N): 
    data.write('{} {} {} ...\n'.format(i, a[0], b[0], ....))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy 
#Assuming a, b are numpy arrays, else convert them accordingly:
# a= np.array(a)
# b= np.array(b)

c = np.zeros((100,40))

for i in range(20):
    c[:, 2*i] = a[:,i]
    c[:, 2*i+1] = b[:,i]

np.savetxt("test.txt",c)
```

This is the simplest way I could think of it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to *interleave* two lists. You can do that with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#zip) and some post-processing of it:

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> b = ['d', 'e', 'f']
>>> print(list(zip(a, b)))
[('a', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'f')]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> print(list(chain.from_iterable(zip(a, b))))
['a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'f']
>>> print(' '.join(chain.from_iterable(zip(a, b))))
a d b e c f
```

You probably want to apply that something like this:

```
data.write('{} {}\n'.format(i, ' '.join(chain.from_iterable(zip(a, b)))))
```